# What makes some Bluetooth devices listed on iOS "My Devices"?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Many devices (such as Bluetooth speakers) are listed in the Setting -> Bluetooth page under "MY DEVICES", when you "pair" to them.

I've noticed that most Bluetooth 4.0 devices aren't listed under even when connected. I used to think this is just the characteristic of BLE 4.0

Recently I encountered a Bluetooth device that should be BLE 4.0 but still shown in the Bluetooth setting page when connected, though there is no option to "forget" and it is gone once disconnected.

Is that just a new thing iOS is doing or is there some mechanism about "pairing" that I should know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS under "My Devices" you will only find BLE peripherals advertising GATT services. So BLE 4.0 peripherals advertising GATT services will also be listed at "My Devices".

Comment: So you mean only when the device is currently broadcasting? Those that has  "forget" listed that's for another mechanism?

Comment: Not all devices advertise with GATT services. That means they won't show up in "My Devices" unless connected, even when the device is broadcasting